# Javascript twoSum algorithm: Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

> Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.
>
> **Example:**
>
> Given nums = `[3, 2, 4]`, target = 6,
>
> Because `nums[1] + nums[2]` = 2 + 4 = 6
>
> `return [1, 2]`.

***Solution***

```
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    for(let i = 0; i <= nums.length; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j <= nums.length; j++){
            if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target){
                return [i, j]
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The code above works in other cases but not this one.

**Expected result** `[1,2]`

**Output** `[0,0]`

For instance, I've tried to use a different array of numbers and a different target and it works even if you change the order of the numbers

**Example:**

New array: `[15, 7, 11, 2]`, target = 9,

**Output:** `[1, 3]`.

I don't understand what is wrong with the solution and I hope that someone can explain. Thanks

Comment: The issue with what you are doing is that j is indexing from 0. So it will consider whatever element resides at i twice. j should always be i+1. As the example you gave, suppose i=0 and j=0, now it will check num[0]+num[0] which is 3+3 and will return 0,0. but the problem states that no number can be used twice. So if you set j=i+1 this way 3+2 !=6 would result in next element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I don't understand what is wrong with the solution and I hope that
>   someone can explain ?

Here you're both inner and outer loop start from `0`<sup>th</sup> so in the case `[3,2,4] and target 6`  it will return `[0,0]` as `3 + 3` is equal to target, so to take care of same index element not being used twice created a difference of `1` between outer and inner loop

---

Make outer loop to start from `0`<sup>th</sup> index and inner loop with value `i+1`

```js
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        for(let j = i+1; j < nums.length; j++){
            if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target){
                return [i, j]
            }
        }
    }
};

console.log(twoSum([15, 7, 11, 2],9))
console.log(twoSum([3, 2, 4],6))
```

Comment: What do you return when you can't find the two numbers?

Comment: @CodeManiac Ah, so it will return `undefined`. I thought you would have to return an empty array.

Comment: @0x499602D2 just wanted to avoid wild guess as there's no info regarding this in question so left it as op's original code, but if i had to do i will always keep return value of same type so that it becomes easier to use the return value from function directly instead of checking type of returned value and then using further operations

Answer (score 12):

You can use a very simple technique.
Basically, you can check if the difference of target & the element in the current iteration, exists in the array.

**Assuming same index cannot be used twice**

```
nums = [3, 2, 4], target = 6
nums[0] = 3
target = 6
diff = 6 - 3 = 3
nums.indexOf[3] = 0 // FAILURE case because it's the same index

// move to next iteration
nums[1] = 2
target = 6
diff = 6 - 2 = 4
nums.indexOf(4) = 2 // SUCCESS '4' exists in the array nums
// break the loop
```

Here's the accepted answer by the [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/submissions/).

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @param {number} target
 * @return {number[]}
 */
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    for (let index = 0; index < nums.length; index++) {
        const diff = target - nums[index];
        const diffIndex = nums.indexOf(diff);
        // "diffIndex !== index" takes care of same index not being reused
        if (diffIndex !== -1 && diffIndex !== index) {
            return [index, diffIndex];
        }
    }
};
```

**Runtime: 72 ms**, faster than 93.74% of JavaScript online submissions for Two Sum.
**Memory Usage: 38.5 MB**, less than 90.55% of JavaScript online submissions for Two Sum.

Can anybody help me in reducing the memory usage also?

Comment: This does not answer *What is wrong with the solution presented?*

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple method to solve this problem and its efficient using different type of inputs using JavaScript.
Like with input of `([3,3], 6)` and its expected output will be `[0,1]` and input like `([3,2,4], 6)` with expected output will be `[2,4]`

```
var twoSum = function (nums, target) {
   for (let i = 0; i <= nums.length; i++) {
     for (let j = 0; j <= nums.length; j++) {
       if (i !== j) {
         if (nums[i] + nums[j] === target) {
           return [i, j];
         }
       }
     }
   }
 };
 console.log(twoSum([3, 2, 4], 6));
```

Comment: This does not answer *What is wrong with the solution presented?*

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer. Since it is not use the _same_ element twice.

Answer (score 2):

we can solve this problem in O(n) by using the map/object.
We can maintain a map or object which will save all values with index and then we can iterate the array and find target-nums[i] for each value and will find that value in map/object.
let's see this by example:-

```
nums=[2,7,11,15]
target = 9;
then map/object will be 
mm={
2 : 0,
7: 1,
11: 2,
15: 3
}


then for each value, we will find diff and find that diff in map/object.
for i=0 diff= 9-2=7 and mm.has(7) is true so our answer is 2 and 7. 
for their index we can use mm.get(7) and i. 
return [mm.get(7), i]
```

```js
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    let mm=new Map();
    for(let i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
        mm.set(nums[i],i);
    }
    let diff=0;
    let j;
    for(let i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
        diff=target-nums[i];
        if(mm.has(diff) && i!=mm.get(diff)){
           j=mm.get(diff);
            if(j>i){
                return [i,j];
            }else{
               return [j,i];
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**Runtime: 76 ms, faster than 88.18% of JavaScript online submissions for Two Sum.
Memory Usage: 41.4 MB, less than 13.32% of JavaScript online submissions for Two Sum.**

Comment: will it work for [2,15,11,2] target is 4, I believe object in JS can contain unique keys only.
mm={
2 : 0, //2:3 will override here
7: 1,
11: 2,}

but anyway 1st element will not be compared by itself i.e 2 in this case.

Comment: in this question, we are considering all elements are unique. IF you want to work with duplicates then you can add an array of indexes. 
2 : [0 ,3]
7 : 1
11 : 2

and while checking this you can check for all possible cases or that question we can solve with other approaches.

Comment: This does not answer *What is wrong with the solution presented?*

Answer (score 1):

Your solution works as expected. For `nums = [3, 2 ,4]` and `target = 6`, `[0, 0]` is a valid solution for the outlined problem as `nums[0] + nums[0] = 3 + 3 = 6`.

If you need two different indices (In my understanding this is not required by the task) you can add an additional check for inequality (`nums[i] + nums[j] == target && i != j`).

Answer (score 1):

```
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    
   for(let i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
       for(let j=i+1; j<nums.length; j++){
           if(nums[j] === target - nums[i]){
              return [i, j];
           }
       }
   }
};
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: This does not answer *What is wrong with the solution presented?*

Answer (score 0):

```
var twoSum = function (nums, target) {
var len = nums.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
        if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
            return [i,j];
        }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I see your vision here, this will be a little bit faster @Mridul

Comment: This does not answer *What is wrong with the solution presented?*

Answer (score 0):

```
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    for(var i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
        for(var j=i+1;j<nums.length;j++){
        temp = nums[i]+nums[j];
        if(temp == target){
            return [i,j]
        }
      }
    }
    
};


console.log(twoSum([15, 7, 11, 2],9))
console.log(twoSum([3, 2, 4],6))
console.log(twoSum([3,3],6))
```

This works perfectly and the Runtime: 72 ms lesser than 84ms

Comment: This does not answer *What is wrong with the solution presented?*

Answer (score 0):

Another efficient solution way to solve this problem with an O(n) time complexity is not using nested loops. I commented the steps, so JS developers can easy understand. Here is my solution using golang:

```
func twoSum(intArray []int, target int) []int {
    response := []int{-1, -1}  // create an array as default response

    if len(intArray) == 0 {  // return default response if the input array is empty
        return response
    }

    listMap := map[int]int{} // create a Map, JS => listMap = new Map()

    for index, value := range intArray { // for loop to fill the map
        listMap[value] = index
    }

    for i, value := range intArray { // for loop to verify if the subtraction is in the map
        result := target - value
        if j, ok := listMap[result]; ok && i != j { // this verify if a property exists on a map in golang. In the same line we verify it i == j.
            response[0] = i
            response[1] = j
            return response
        }
    }

    return response
}
```

Comment: This does not answer *What is wrong with the solution presented?*

Answer (score 0):

```
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    var numlen = nums.length;
    for(let i=0; i<=numlen; i++){
        for(let j=i+1;j<numlen;j++){
            var num1 = parseInt(nums[i]);
            var num2 = parseInt(nums[j]);
            var num3 = num1 + num2;
            if(num3 == target){
            return[i,j]
            }
        }
    }
    
    
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This does not answer *What is wrong with the solution presented?*

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this could be a better solution. Instead of nesting loops, this provides a linear solution.

(PS: *indexOf* is kinda a loop too with O(n) complexity)

```
var twoSum = function (nums, target) {
    const hm = {}
    nums.forEach((num, i) => {
      hm[target - num] = i
    })

    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      if(hm[nums[i]] !== undefined && hm[nums[i]] !== i) {
        return ([hm[nums[i]], i])
      }
    }
};
```

Comment: This does not answer *What is wrong with the solution presented?*

Answer (score 0):

```
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
        if(  nums.indexOf(target - nums[i]) !== -1)
        {
            return [i , nums.indexOf(target - nums[i])]
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: This does not answer *What is wrong with the solution presented?*

Answer (score 0):

**For clearity console a & b in inner for loop . This will give you clear insight**

```
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
var arr=[];
  
for(var a=0;a<nums.length;a++){
    for(var b=1;b<nums.length;b++){
        let c=nums[a]+nums[b];
       
        if(c== target  && a != b){
            
           arr[0]=a;
            arr[1]=b;
            
        }
    }
}   
  return arr;   
};
```

Comment: This does not answer *What is wrong with the solution presented?*

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1. Create a Set
2. Then loop the array for retrieve all the differences between the target number minus all the elements in array. Insert only which are positive (*as is a Set, duplicates will not be included*).
3. Then iterates array again, now only compare if array elements is in the set, if yes take the index from *i* store in the index array and return it.

```
public static Object solution(int[] a, int target){
    Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
    for (int e : a){
        Integer diff = new Integer(target - e);
        if(diff>0){
            s.add(diff);
        }
    }
    
    int i = 0;
    for (int e : a){
        if(s.contains(e)){
            indexes.add(i);
        }
        i++;
    }
    

    return indexes;
    
}
```

Comment: This does not answer *What is wrong with the solution presented?*

Answer (score 0):

```
def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        comp = target - nums[i]
        if comp in nums:
            j = nums.index(comp)
                if(i!=j):
                    return [i,j]
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: This does not answer *What is wrong with the solution presented?* It does not use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        for(let j = i+1; j < nums.length; j++){
            if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target){
                return [i, j]
            }
        }
    }
};

console.log(twoSum([15, 7, 11, 2],9))
console.log(twoSum([3, 2, 4],6))
```

Comment: This does not answer *What is wrong with the solution presented?*

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        indx =[]
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for j in range(i+1,len(nums)):
                if nums[j]==(target-nums[i]):
                    indx.append(i)
                    indx.append(j)
                    return indx
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not answer *What is wrong with the solution presented?*

Answer (score 0):

```
twoSummation = (numsArr, estTarget) => {
    for(let index = 0; index < numsArr.length; index++){
        for(let n = index+1; n < numsArr.length; n++){
            if(numsArr[index] + numsArr[n] == estTarget){
                return [index, n]
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(twoSummation([2,7,11,15], 9))
console.log(twoSummation([3,2,4], 6))
```

Comment: This does not answer *What is wrong with the solution presented?*

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    

<script>
 var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    for(var i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
        for(var j=i+1;j<nums.length;j++){
        temp = nums[i]+nums[j];
        if(temp == target){
            return [nums[i],nums[j]]
        }
      }
    }
    
};
console.log(twoSum([15, 7, 11, 2],9))
console.log(twoSum([3, 2, 4],6))
console.log(twoSum([3,3],6))
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is a code only answer. To make it more helpful to the asker, you could provide some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Solution from my leetcode submission in Java. Top 75% in runtime, top 25% in memory. It is 0(n) however uses an external HashMap.

```
import java.util.HashMap; 

class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> numbers= new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
            int cur = nums[i];
            numbers.put(cur, i);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
            //check map for diff of target - cur
            int diff = target - nums[i];
            if(numbers.containsKey(diff) && numbers.get(diff)!=i){
                return new int[]{i, numbers.get(diff)};
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addNumber(num, target) {
   let arr = [];
   num.every((pv, pi) => {
      let diff = target - pv;
      let diffIdx = num.indexOf(diff);
      if (diffIdx !== -1 && diffIdx !== pi) {
          arr.push(pi,diffIdx)
          return false;
      }
      return true;
   });
    return arr;
  }

console.log(
    addNumber([4, 0, 1, 9, 7],4)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a[] = { 2, 4, 6 };
        for (int i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
                if (a[i] + a[j] == 10) {
                    int and[] = { i, j };
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ans));
                }
            }
        }        
    }
}
```