# Problem in returning indices of two numbers in array

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have this problem:

> Given an array of integers `nums` and an integer `target`, return the indices of two numbers that add up to `target`.

**Example 1:**

```
Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9
Output: [0,1]
Output: Because nums[0] + nums[1] == 9, we return [0, 1].
```

With the code below was able to get the values added in array using `set` and `Map`

What I need help is to return the indices

```
const arr = [{key1: 2}, {key1: 7}, {key1: 11}, {key1: 15}];
const k = 9;
const valueSet = new Set(arr.flatMap((x) => Object.values(x)));
const valueArray = [...valueSet];

valueArray.forEach((v1, i1) => {
    for (let i2 = i1 + 1; i2 < valueArray.length; i2++) {
        if ((v1 + valueArray[i2]) === k) {
            // Return the indices
            return valueArray[i2];
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: For each doesn't return anything

Comment: There is already an answer for similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57544749/javascript-twosum-algorithm-given-an-array-of-integers-return-indices-of-the-t

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript twoSum algorithm: Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57544749/javascript-twosum-algorithm-given-an-array-of-integers-return-indices-of-the-t)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to parse and find the combination of indexes which gives you the sum.

Below code will help you

```js
const arr = [{ key1: 2 }, { key1: 7 }, { key1: 11 }, { key1: 15 }];
const k = 9;
let valueSet = new Set(arr.flatMap((x) => Object.values(x)));
let valueArray = [...valueSet];

let indices;
let isFound = false;
// valueArray.forEach((v1, i1) => {
for (let i1 = 0; i1 < valueArray.length && !isFound; i1++) {
  for (let i2 = i1 + 1; i2 < valueArray.length && !isFound; i2++) {
    if ((valueArray[i1] + valueArray[i2]) === k) {
      //Return the Indices
      indices = [i1, i2];
      isFound = true;;
    }
  }
}
console.log(indices);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by [Nitheesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70210777/11695068) works well. As for an explanation as to why your initial approach was not successful:

Using `forEach` to iterate over an array is different than using traditional for loops, in that the callback function is called for every element on the array. Using `return` in a `forEach` loop just breaks out of *that particular element's callback*, but not the entire iteration (hence, a `return` in a `forEach` loop behaves similarly to a `continue` in a `for (...)` loop.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#description).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the array with the values from your array with keys  `[{key1: 2},{key1: 7},{key1: 11},{key1: 15}];`. Then you loop the value array and return the index if the condition `(nums[i] + nums[j] == target)` => `(7 + 2 == 9)` is true.

```js
const arr = [{key1: 2},{key1: 7},{key1: 11},{key1: 15}];
const k = 9;
nums = arr.map((o) => {
  return Object.values(o)[0]
})

const twoSum = (nums, target) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        for(let j = i+1; j < nums.length; j++){
            if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target){
                return [i, j]
            }
        }
    }
};

console.log(twoSum(nums, k))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this should do it:

```js
function indice1(target, arr) {
  let result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[i] + arr[j] === target) {
        return (result = [arr[i], arr[j]]);
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}

function indice2(target, arr) {
  let result = [];

  for (const i of arr) {
    for (const j of arr) {
      if (i + j === target) {
        return (result = [i, j]);
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}

function indice3(target, arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, curr, i, arr) => {
    let result = [...acc, curr];

    for (const i of acc) {
      if (i + curr === target) {
        result = [i, curr];
        arr.splice(1);
        break;
      }
    }

    return result;
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [{ key1: 2 }, { key1: 7 }, { key1: 11 }, { key1: 15 }];
const k = 9;
let valueSet = new Set(arr.flatMap((x) => Object.values(x)));
let valueArray = [...valueSet];

valueArray.forEach((v,ind) => {
    let ind2 = valueArray.findIndex(iv => iv === k - v)
    ind2 > -1 && console.log([ind,ind2])
})
```